# table view calling an error when passing data xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have been following a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12865/how-to-make-a-simple-playing-card-game-with-multiplayer-and-bluetooth-part-2)

It uses calls to change to table view which I do not want to use and have not added this but when it comes to this point

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //if (cell == nil) cell = [[PeerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSString *peerID = [_matchmakingServer peerIDForConnectedClientAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [_matchmakingServer displayNameForPeerID:peerID];

    return cell;
}
```

I blanked out the if statement as this is where it will set the format for the data and now when you return cell it throws up an exception

Anyone got any ideas why?

Error Message...

> > Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:5471 2013-05-29
> >     21:11:28.967 Iphone_controller[2485:907] *** Terminating app due to
> >     uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
> >     'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from
> >     tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: "it uses's a calls to change the to table view" Say what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it throws an exception because you're returning `nil`. Because you commented out the line where the cell would have been created... Not sure why you did that.

Technically, your code could work, but only if you register a NIB with the table view for your `CellIdentifier` before you try to use the table view.

Creating the cell if one can't be dequeued is the common and correct thing to do if you aren't registering the NIB.

Try:

```
    if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: I commented t out as it uses a style sheet for the table which i do not have in my project and wouldn't compile with that line in what do you suggest i replace it with?

Comment: Instantiate a UITableViewCell instead of a PeerCell

Comment: It's the same thing, just instantiating the different class:

if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];